# <script> tag doesn't close properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-roo

In my default.jspx which contains the basic layout for the page I am trying to import some jquery libraries as follows

```
<head>
    ...
    <spring:url value="/resources/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" var="jquery_url" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/js/lib/jquery.tokeninput.js" var="jquery_tokeninput_url" />
    <script src="${jquery_url}" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="${jquery_tokeninput_url}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();
    </script>
    <util:load-scripts />
    ...
</head>
```

but when the page is rendered in the browser the first script tag swallows the two others

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/roo-inari/resources/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
//These lines are inside the first script tag
<script type="text/javascript" src="/roo-inari/resources/js/lib/jquery.tokeninput.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();
//The tag is closed here
</script>
<link href="/roo-inari/resources/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

Any idea what might be causing this? The project is based on a spring roo generated web mvc scaffold.
I am using Chrome v.25.

Comment: I don't know Spring, but if your JSP source has `</script>` on the end of the two lines that are parsed for server variables, there's seemingly some reason that Spring or something server is outputting that. And if you're not copying that from the *actual page source* (right-click, View Source), then show that.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure why the downvotes. I don't know [tag:spring-mvc] but this seems odd alright that the HTML ends up like that as your script tags seem well formed and look fine in the page, assuming the `src` is a valid value for [tag:spring-mvc].

Comment: +1 I'm not sure why the downvotes (please explain if you do), I ran across this exact same issue and this describes it perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple solution was to write a comment inside the tag so that it is not closed automatically. Silly me

```
<script src="${jquery_url}" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for some browsers --></script>
```

Comment: +1 as this sounds like something future users with similar issues will probably find useful. As soon as SO lets you, mark this answer as accepted too.

Comment: The explaination of this is that the parser gobbles up the ending tags when an element has nothing inside.  As @Pyhtos suggested, placing a commend inside the empty script tags fixes the issue.  I ran into this a year ago, and I believe the explaination had something to do with XHTML.