# Script Tag doesn't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a Website which contains a Table plugin. The plugin get's imported by a `<script>` tag and executed with javascript. Besides I use Bootstrap so the bootstrap.min.js file is importet too. Here is how it looks:

```
         <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

         <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready( function () {
                        $('#table_id').DataTable();
               } );
          </script>
```

All this code is placed right before closeing the `<body>` tag. If I upload the file on my webspace and visit the page, no script get's executed. If I take a look at the source-code in Chrome, all I see is that the `<script>` tag doesn't close properly:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
        <script charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function () {
                    $('#table_id').DataTable();
            } );    
    </script>
```

I already tried to place the scripts on diffrent places in the code, but everytime there's the same problem. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716706/script-tag-doesnt-close-properly) answer, but the comments don't even get displayed in the source-code.

Is there any proper way to solve this problem?

(UPDATE: Complete Code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>



    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <table id="table_id" class="display">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Column 1</th>
                                    <th>Column 2</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                                    <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                                    <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function () {
                    $('#table_id').DataTable();
            } );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any log in console ?

Comment: Works fine when I paste it in a fiddle. What browsers did you test?

Comment: It's probably coming from something that you haven't posted. Probably something before your `script` tags.

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman No, the console stays empty

Comment: @kalsowerus I'm testing it in Google Chrome (56.0.2924.87)

Comment: @IAP15B_eliareutlinger Could you post the entire html document?

Comment: Does any software touch your HTML file before you look at it in the browser? In your below example the inner script tags also seem get corrupted. Also test other browser though, as chrome is not always perfect.

Comment: @Maincore --> Question Updated

Comment: Pasted your code in a text file, saved as html, opened in browser, tag looks fine in source view.

Answer (score 0):

```
// You are not closing scripts tag

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"/></script>
        <script charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function () {
                    $('#table_id').DataTable();
            } );   
</script>
```

Comment: This is the result he is getting in his browser. Hovewer, in the source code, tags are closed correcly.

Comment: Sure I do. But they are not closed later on in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any issue here, but why dont you try a self closing script tag for loading jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
<script charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function () {
                    $('#table_id').DataTable();
            });    
    </script>
```

Comment: I already did, but the same problem appears. The tag won't be closed ploperly

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong charset. It's `utf-8`, not `utf8`.

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations